# Getting Wrong Output from Operations Performed Between Two Pipe Delimited Files Converted to 2D Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I'm new to coding and my instructions for this problem are:
"Given pipe-delimited files F1 and F2 where F1 contains accounts with fields ACCOUNT NUM|PIN|BALANCE and F2 contains transaction instructions COMMAND|AMOUNT|ACCOUNT NUM|PIN, execute the transactions, storing the results back in F1.

The COMMAND field will be add or sub indicating addition or subtraction from the account.

Transactions which do not provide the correct PIN code or attempt to put the account below zero should be ignored."

My output is:

```
1000|1234|10000
1020|2222|0
3000|3344|1000
2020|1234|90000
```

The correct output is:

```
1000|1234|11000
1020|2222|0
3000|3344|0
2020|1234|90000
```

The code I've written is:

```
import sys
F1= sys.argv[1] 
F2= sys.argv[2]

records=[]
with open(F1,'r') as fp:
  content=fp.readlines()
  for row in content:
    recList=row.strip("\n").split('|')
    records.append(recList)

records2=[]
with open(F2,'r') as fp:
  content=fp.readlines()
  for row in content:
    recList2=row.strip("\n").split('|')
    records2.append(recList2)

for i in range(len(records)):
  row=records[i]
for i in range(len(records2)):
  row=records2[i]
for row in records and records2:
  if records[i][1]==records2[i][3]:
    if records2[i][0]=="add":
      records[i][2]=int(records[i][2])+int(records2[i][1])
    elif records2[i][0]=="sub":
      if int(records[i][2])>=int(records2[i][1]):
        records[i][2]=int(records[i][2])-int(records2[i][1])
      else:
        records[i][2]=records[i][2]
  else:
    break
print(records)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the COMMANDS. The last numbers displayed in your output rows are without the addition or subtraction, which is why they are wrong.

Comment: Your remark is bit vague, try to answer with a working solution along with pointing out an error.

Comment: @Mercurial, I see this post is from 10 months ago but the information I provided to the asker is relevant to the assignment and if the original poster read the assignment he would find he didn't pass the checkpoint because the assignment asks for the ability to do commands labeled "ADD" and "SUB". I didn't feel the need to post something that the poster already has access to.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Create a function that turns pipe-delimited strings into 2d arrays
def pipe2a(text):
  records= text.split("\n")
  for i in range(0, len(records)):
    records[i]= records[i].split("|")
  return records

# Create a function that turns 2d arrays into pipe-delimited strings.
def a2pipe(a):
  text= ""
  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    account= a[i]
    for j in range(0, len(account)):
      account[j]= str(account[j])
     text = text + "|".join(account) + "\n"
  return text;

# Read in the accounts and transactions
accounts= pipe2a(open(F1, 'r').read())
transactions= pipe2a(open(F2, 'r').read())

# Main Section
# for each transaction
for transactionIndex in range(0, len(transactions)):
  transaction= transactions[transactionIndex]
  if(len(transaction) >= 4):
    # look through the accounts for the matching account
    for accountIndex in range(0,len(accounts)):
      account= accounts[accountIndex]
      if(len(account) >= 3):                      # make sure we have
        balance= int(account[2])                  # enough fields
        transactionAmount= int(transaction[1])
        if(account[0] == transaction[2]):         # account matches?
          if(account[1] == transaction[3]):       # pin code matches?
            if(transaction[0] == 'add'):
              accounts[accountIndex][2]= balance + transactionAmount
            elif (transaction[0] == 'sub' and transactionAmount <= balance):
              accounts[accountIndex][2]= balance - transactionAmount


# Write the answer back out to the original file
open(F1, 'w').write(a2pipe(accounts))
```

It works

Comment: You forgot to close the file F1 when you were done with it (OP used `with open` syntax to ensure the file is closed). Also, you forgot to declare the variables F1 and F2 in your code snippet. Finally, there are ample opportunities to make your code easier to read. 
`for transactionIndex in range(0, len(transactions)):
  transaction= transactions[transactionIndex]`
is much harder to understand than `for transaction in transactions:`